# Is there any reason to not use KEY_WOW64_64KEY?

Tags: windows, registry

According to [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724878(v=vs.85).aspx) KEY_WOW64_64KEY and KEY_WOW64_32KEY forces the application to operate on the 64-bit or 32-bit registry, respectively. Are there any risks to always using KEY_WOW64_64KEY? If I convert my 32-bit application to 64-bit in the future, I can rely on the registry keys being in the same place if the user installs the update.

When should I use the 32-bit registry instead? I guess if I wanted to support installing both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the application side-by-side, but usually you wouldn't want that.

Comment: No reason I'm aware of, assuming of course that you are talking about registry entries that only your application will look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main reasons for this option:

The first is if you upgrade your application from x86 to x64; if you don't explicitly pass the registry in the options (which older applications often won't), your x64 build won't be able to retrieve any registry keys that were set by the x86 build.

The second is for reading information from system registry keys. There is sometimes OS information that isn't exposed by winapi and only exists in one registry or the other.

If you're writing a new application, it's not an issue; you can explicitly use one registry or the other and not worry.